# Clear cache on webview when the app is killed

Tags: android, caching, android-webview, android-lifecycle, android-ondestroy

I have seen other answers on stackoverflow but none of them helped me solve my issue.

I have an application with webview in a activity, I want to clear cache when the application is killed.

Below is the code I'm using to delete the cache-

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
        return dir.delete();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

I want to clear cache when application is killed or just before the app is going to be killed, where do I call `deleteCache(this)`?

I tried putting it in `OnDestroy()` method of the activity , but it clears the cache when I press back button on the activity which is **not my requirement**.

So I added

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

So my activity doesn't call onDestroy() at all when I press back button nor I kill the application.

Where do I need to clear the cache on the lifecycle methods ?
and
Where can I trigger an event to javascript function just before my app is killed?

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465432/android-webview-completely-clear-the-cache

Comment: @AlvinVarghese That question was more of not using cache at all in the application. So he clears cache when the webview loads. Not in my case, I want clear it when the application is destroyed.

Comment: You can try the below link to determine if you application is killed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040339/how-to-know-when-my-app-has-been-killed

Comment: You won't get any callbacks invoked if the system "decides" to kill your app process being in background. If you, as a developer, can't rely on that, maybe you should rethink the approach to the problem?... What you know for sure is that your app process is created the [`Application`'s `onCreate()` method is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101071/application-lifecycle-when-app-is-killed-in-the-background/43101601#43101601). So why not clear the cache from within the method, i.e. not upon the app killing, but upon its launch?

Comment: @Onik Thanks for your input it makes sense but I followed this approach [OnClearService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040339/how-to-know-when-my-app-has-been-killed) and  created a service and cleared my cache at onTaskRemoved();

Comment: _"...created a service and cleared my cache at onTaskRemoved()"_ A good approach! But, from my experience, in rare cases `onTaskRemoved()` isn't guaranteed to be called. I recommend to test the method call for different OS versions (and ideally for a range of devices). Additional notes on the method call can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072294/when-can-ontaskremoved-be-called/40072391#40072391).

Comment: @Onik Awesome, I'll test it out on some devices. Seems like I need to follow - Application's OnCreate() method approach, as you have already done hell lot of research on this . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get any callbacks invoked if the system "decides" to kill your app being in background. If you, as a developer, can't rely on that, maybe you should rethink the approach to the problem?...

What you know for sure is that when your app process is created the [`Application`'s `onCreate()` method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43101071/application-lifecycle-when-app-is-killed-in-the-background/43101601#43101601). So why not clear the cache from within the method, i.e. not upon the app killing, but upon its launch?

> I followed [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040339/how-to-know-when-my-app-has-been-killed) and created a service and cleared my cache at `onTaskRemoved()`.

Good approach, but, from my experience, in rare cases `onTaskRemoved()` isn't guaranteed to be called. I recommend to test the method call for different OS versions (and ideally for a range of devices). Also note that [`onTaskRemoved()` is only called when a user removes your app from the recent task list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072294/when-can-ontaskremoved-be-called/40072391#40072391).

To sum up, if you use `Application`'s `onCreate()` to clear the cache, the operation is guaranteed to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this before leaving the activity

WebView.clearCache(true);

Comment: What do you mean by leaving the activity? You mean onDestroy() ? Please check my question.

Comment: yes u can put in onDestroy or write finish(), when u navigate to another activity

Comment: OnDestroy will be called when I press backbutton. I want to clear cache when I kill the application. Again please check my question !

Comment: if your webview activity is the last activity of ur app then it will work. Otherwise u can use a service before killing the app just stop the service.